# Change the colour of text in the footer of a Word document

Tags: vba, footer, ms-word, word-2010

I'm using VBA to insert some text in to the footer of a document, and I wish to then change the colour of the text.

I've tried using `Selection.Range.Font.ColorIndex` but this doesn't seem to work. I've also tried manually settings the colour and recording a macro, but VBA doesn't pick up on the colour change.

Does anybody know how I can achieve this? Thanks.

```
'**
 ' Insert the required text into the footer of the document
 '
 ' @param required String footerText    The text to insert into the document footer
 ' @param Boolean insertDate            Whether or no to insert the date into the document footer
 '*
Sub DoFooterText(ByVal footerText As String, _
                 Optional ByVal insertDate As Boolean = True)

    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Count:=2                       ' Go to page 2 of the document (no footer on page 1)
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1                 ' Move the cursor to the right of the document
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekPrimaryFooter     ' Switch the view to the header
    Selection.TypeText text:=footerText                             ' Insert the footer text
    If insertDate = True Then                                       ' Insert the date into the footer
        Selection.TypeText text:=vbCrLf
        Selection.InsertDateTime _
            DateTimeFormat:="dd/MM/yyyy", _
            InsertAsField:=False, _
            InsertAsFullWidth:=False, _
            DateLanguage:=wdEnglishUK, _
            CalendarType:=wdCalendarWestern
    End If
    Selection.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdGray50                      ' Set the colour of the footer text
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument      ' Switch the view back to the main document
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory                                 ' Move the cursor back to the top of the document

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the text where you want to change the color first. Try adding the line below, right before the line where you set the color of the text.

It's the equivalent of pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>:

```
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend

Selection.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdGray50                      ' Set the colour of the footer text
```

**EDIT**:

If you want to select all of the text in the footer, from where the text is entered to the beginning of the footer (the equivalent of pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>), use `Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdExtend` instead.

Comment: Also, you might want to add a space between `footerText`and the date?

Comment: Good spot, I'd accidently removed `Selection.TypeText text:=vbCrLf` before outputting the date.  As for your answer it's working on date but not the `footerText`, which is now a line above. Thanks.

Comment: Ah ha, changing `wdLine` to `wdStory` does the trick.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: OK, great! (I just assumed they were on the same line)

Comment: Right, I've updated the answer to include your comment about selecting both lines.

Comment: Well from the code I origianlly posted you would have been correct, it's just becuase I'd removed that one line by mistake. Thanks again.